# How to pass values from handler to middleware in golang?

Tags: go

I tried to pass some values from handler to middleware but it is not working
Handler

```
func (s *Server) handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //code
    v := map[string]string{
        "created_by":   CreatedBy,
        "name": Name,
    }
    context.WithValue(r.Context(), "result", v)
    api.Send(w, http.StatusOK, value)
}
```

middleware

```
func activity(next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        result := getParams(r.Context())
        fmt.Println("result", result)

    })
}


func getParams(ctx context.Context) map[string]string {
    if ctx == nil {
        return nil
    }

    result, ok := ctx.Value("result").(map[string]string)
    if ok {
        return result
    }

    return nil
}
```

after receiving value from the context it shows like empty map.is any other method to pass some values from the handler to the middleware.

Comment: [Per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue), `context.WithValue` doesn't modify the context (because contexts are immutable), it returns a new context with the value added, which you're discarding.

Comment: @Adrian How it possible to get inside the middleware?

Answer (score 2):

In you case, You have to create a `copy` of the `http.Request` with new context

```
v := map[string]string{
    "created_by":   CreatedBy,
    "name": Name,
}
rcopy := r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "result", v))
```

Then you have to "send" the `http.Request` through all handlers (`firstHandler -> activity -> lastHandler` )

```
func main() {
    //firstHandler ➡️ activity ➡️ lastHandler`
    http.Handle("/", firstHandler(activity(lastHandler())))
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}


func firstHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        v := map[string]string{
            "created_by": CreatedBy,
            "name":       Name,
        }
        rcopy := r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "result", v))
        next.ServeHTTP(w, rcopy)
    })
}

func activity(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        result := getParams(r.Context())
        fmt.Println("activity result", result)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func lastHandler() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        result := getParams(r.Context())
        fmt.Println("last result", result)
    })
}
```

Comment: Inside handler 
`
func (s *Server) handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     v := map[string]string{
  "created_by":   CreatedBy,
  "default_name": Name,
 }
 r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "result", v))

}

`

in middleware i called like this `  fmt.Println("result", r.Context().Value("result"))
`
still getting empty map